# How to reassign mutable String?

Tags: string, rust

Why does reassigning a mutable String results in compile error? Shouldn't `mut` allow mutating string?

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut guess = String::from("foo\n");
    guess = guess.trim();
    println!("Input: {}", guess);
}
```

Gives

```
9 |     guess = guess.trim();
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^- help: try using a conversion method: `.to_string()`
  |             |
  |             expected struct `String`, found `&str`
```

Comment: Trim returns a string slice

Comment: Yes! what would be proper way to trim whitespace and then modify String later? Do you have to recreate new String with `let guess = guess.trim()`?

Comment: You cannot assign a string slice to a string, the compiler is correct here, change the line to what it suggests, `guess = guess.trim().to_string();`